# VMWare Fusion - External access private IP when no network available

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have IIS running in Windows 8 in a VM on my Mac. With the Networking set to Bridged mode I can access IIS from my Mac using the IP address. This works fine when I'm connected to my network.

What I need to be able to do is access IIS from my Mac when there is no network connection available, and I can't figure it out.

Background: This is so that I can demo a web app to clients in situations where I have no 3G coverage and they don't have wifi I can connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to go to Virtual Machine -> Network Adapter -> Network Adapter Settings, then select Private To My Mac.

The VM won't be able to connect to the internet, but your Mac should be able to connect to the VM on the IP that it's assigned, even when there's no internet connection.

Remember to add rules, or turn off Windows firewall in order to let traffic through to IIS though.